# Error 404 on PUT request while having a GET

Tags: spring, rest, http-status-code-404, spring-restcontroller, http-status-code-405

Got a small problem on my rest server. It's based on spring web framework.

Here's the code that poses me problems :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
public class usersWS {

    //some other functions

    //works
    @RequestMapping(
        value="/{iduser}/functions/",
        method=RequestMethod.GET,
        produces={"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUserFunctions(@PathVariable("iduser") String iduser){
        //do stuff
        return stuff;
    }

    //Don't works
    @RequestMapping(
        value="/{iduser}/functions/"
        method=RequestMethod.PUT,
        consumes={"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<String> addUserFunctions(@RequestBody String json, @PathVariable("iduser") String iduser){
        //do stuff
        return stuff;
    }

}
```

Server is launched by :

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@ImportResource("classpath*:**/jdbc-context.xml")
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

To call this server, I use the HTML handler found here : [Spring HTTP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338176/spring-http-client)

When I call the get verb, everything is working fine. I get the iduser, get the data I want, no problem.

When I call the put verb... I have an error 404. I checked, the url (http://localhost:8080/users/xxx/functions/) are exactly the same, I do send the body.

I would understand to get a 405 error, but I really don't understand how I can have a 404. If the mapping was wrong, the server should at least see that there is a function on the get verb and throw me a 405.

I have other functions using the PUT/POST that are working but they don't have a @PathVariable. Is it possible to mix @RequestBody and @PathVariable ?

Any help is gladly welcome.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've written using the Spring RestTemplate to call your REST services?

Comment: Service is launched by a simple : (edited the main post)

Comment: Also have you tried testing your PUT using something like Postman?

Comment: I did not. Will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Damn... Thanks for your advise, Postman allowed me to have some more details.

The 404 was returned by my service because one of the user I was loading was not found. As I have managed the http return code, it throws me a 404.

So the code himself is working.

Thanks a lot mate.